# PowerShell script to change desktop wallpaper images and lock screen images w/o logging into each account?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, images, desktop, lock-screen

I want to know how I can make a PowerShell script that changes all of the desktop background images and lock screen images to (different) specific images without logging into each account.

I'm trying to create a script that changes the desktop background for "user 1" to one picture and "user 2" to a different picture, and so on. So far I've figured out how to add the pictures to file through PowerShell, but I've been applying them manually by logging into to one account at a time. I'm not sure how to go about applying the images from their folder to the desktop background and/or lock screen.

This is what I have so far:

```
# Save pictures to the correct directory

New-Item -ItemType directory -Path C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages

If (test-path "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo1.jpg*"){Remove-Item "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo1.jpg"}
Copy-Item "E:\USB\photo1.jpg*" -Destination "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages"

If (test-path "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo2.jpg*"){Remove-Item "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo2.jpg"}
Copy-Item "E:\USB\photo2.jpg*" -Destination "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages"

If (test-path "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo3.jpg*"){Remove-Item "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo3.jpg*"}
Copy-Item "E:\USB\photo3.jpg*" -Destination "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages"

If (test-path "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo4.jpg*"){Remove-Item "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo4.jpg*"}
Copy-Item "E:\USB\photo4.jpg*" -Destination "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages"

If (test-path "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo5.jpg*"){Remove-Item "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages\photo5.jpg*"}
Copy-Item "E:\USB\photo5.jpg*" -Destination "C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper\CompanyImages"

Write-Host "Images have been successfully copied. "
#Apply desktop images
#Apply Lock-screen image
```

Comment: (A bit) related: ["Powershell script from shortcut to change desktop" on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9440135/8013879)

Comment: Should the lock screen background for an account be the same image as its desktop background? Changing the desktop background for a different account is pretty doable, but setting a specific account's lock screen will be difficult.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a GPO?

Comment: We don't have active directory so I was hoping to make a script that I could apply to multpile computers in order to save time.

Comment: The desktop backgrounds for each account should be different. The Lockscreen image should be the same for every user.